# HashMap inside a HashMap

Tags: java, hashmap

I want to make sure this is correct, because if it isn't it might just break my app.

I have this:

```
private static HashMap<String, HashMap<String, Double>> balance = new HashMap<>();
```

If I get the value like this:

```
balance.get("something").put("something",100);
```

When I get the HashMap again like the above method does it stay recorded?

I'm almost positive the answer is yes, but is it?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please include all of the relevant code; the formatting may be eating it, or you may not have posted it all. Also, please be specific about what you're asking; what are you meaning by "get the hashmap", and what's the "it" you're asking about?

Comment: Yes; objects are passed by reference.

Comment: Don't forget you have to `put` a `HashMap` before you get it.

Comment: If you're unsure, you can always try writing a test to exercise the condition you're curious about.

Comment: @SLaks Object references are passed by value.

Comment: Object references are pointers to actual objects. As long as you have `1+balance.size()` actual instantiated HashMaps, you can make unlimited references to them and be fine. Afaict this code just edits one of them.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you've already put() a HashMap with a key of "something", then yes, calling `balance.get("something").get("something")` will return 100.0.

There's one problem with your sample code, though; it won't compile unless you change `100` to `100d`.  `100` is an int; you express 100 as a double with `100d` (or `100.0`, or cast it).